# CSS - Responsive Testimonial Slider text is not resizing even tho the slider is set at 100% width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Responsive Testimonial Slider text is not resizing even tho the slider is set at 100% width
all the other classes and divs are also set at 100% but for some reason when I resize the screen it stays large and is cut off on the screen.

JSFiddle Demo Here: https://jsfiddle.net/fjkL61va/

---

Html

---

```
<div id="slides" style="background:red;">

  <ul>

    <li class="slide">
        <h2>"m gravida elit vitae volutpat ornare. Morbi pellentesque vehicula urna ut sagittis. Nunc euismod fermentum vehicula."</h2>
    </li>

    <li class="slide">
      <h2>"m gravida elit vitae volutpat ornare. Morbi pellentesque vehicula urna ut sagittis. Nunc euismod fermentum vehicula."</h2> 
    </li>

    <li class="slide">
        <h2>"m gravida elit vitae volutpat ornare. Morbi pellentesque vehicula urna ut sagittis. Nunc euismod fermentum vehicula."</h2>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>


  <div id="buttons">

    <a id="prev" href="#">&lt;</a>

    <a id="next" href="#">&gt;</a>

  </div>
```

---

CSS

---

```
#slides {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
  }

  #slides ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
  }

  #slides li {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }

  #prev {
    float: left;
    font-size: 300%;

  }
  #next {
    float: right;
    font-size: 300%;

  }
```

---

Javascript

---

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
  //rotation speed and timer
  var speed = 5000;

  var run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
  var slides = $('.slide');
  var container = $('#slides ul');
  var elm = container.find(':first-child').prop("tagName");
  var item_width = container.width();
  var previous = 'prev'; //id of previous button
  var next = 'next'; //id of next button
  slides.width(item_width); //set the slides to the correct pixel width
  container.parent().width(item_width);
  container.width(slides.length * item_width); //set the slides container to the correct total width
  container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));
  resetSlides();


  //if user clicked on prev button

  $('#buttons a').click(function (e) {
    //slide the item

    if (container.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    if (e.target.id == previous) {
      container.stop().animate({
        'left': 0
      }, 1500, function () {
        container.find(elm + ':first').before(container.find(elm + ':last'));
        resetSlides();
      });
    }

    if (e.target.id == next) {
      container.stop().animate({
        'left': item_width * -2
      }, 1500, function () {
        container.find(elm + ':last').after(container.find(elm + ':first'));
        resetSlides();
      });
    }

    //cancel the link behavior      
    return false;

  });

  //if mouse hover, pause the auto rotation, otherwise rotate it  
  container.parent().mouseenter(function () {
    clearInterval(run);
  }).mouseleave(function () {
    run = setInterval(rotate, speed);
  });


  function resetSlides() {
    //and adjust the container so current is in the frame
    container.css({
      'left': -1 * item_width
    });
  }

});
//a simple function to click next link
//a timer will call this function, and the rotation will begin

function rotate() {
  $('#next').click();
}
```

Comment: You can do the whole thing with CSS only

Comment: It looks like your `100%` on `.slides` is being canceled out with absolute px values. I'll try and fix it for you.

Comment: @user4875251 Thank you, I have just noticed that if I resize the page and then refresh it then resizes to the screen correctly, any idea why is is?

Comment: In your js, you call `var item_width = container.width();` Which is essentially saying that the slides (var item_width) = the slides container (width). Which means, when you refresh at full screen, your container would be x-amount of width. For example `900px`. So your js is telling your code to make your slides `900px` which cancels out your `100%.

Comment: @user4875251 thank you I see how would I change my Js so that its 100% instead?

Comment: I was using `var item_width = 100 + "%";` But then you run into a problem of not getting the text boxes to float lol

Comment: Sorry man, i can't seem to get a solution, I have to go to work, if it's not solved when I get home tonight I can probably try again. Good luck! If you can't figure it out, there are plenty of tutorials for responsive sliders online.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries for Text.